# How to Create a Key and Bind the Array Values in Multidimensional Way PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have data here:

Here's the result of my first function.The variable I used for the result was $this->arrays.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array //Transactiondetails of SiteID 1
    (
        [SiteID] => 1
        [Balance] => 2000
        [MinBalance] => 1000
        [MaxBalance] => 500
        [OwnerAID] => 1
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 10000
        [Reload] => 0
        [Redemption] => 0
    )
  )
```

Now, here's the result of my second function.The variable I used for the result was $this->combined.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [AID] => 1
        [Sites] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1 //List of SiteID owned by AID                   
                [1] => 5
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [AID] => 3
        [Sites] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4 //SiteID
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [AID] => 4
        [Sites] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1 //SiteID
            )
    )

 )
```

I try it with this code:

```
 public function createListOfCorpOwnedSites()
 {

 foreach ($this->combined as &$site) {

            $aids = array();

            foreach ($this->result_array as $acct) {
              if ($acct['SiteID'] === $site['SiteID'])
                $aids[] = $acct['AID'];
              }
              $site['CorpAID'] = $aids;
            }

            print_r($this->combined );

            }
```

But, I need a better result, The first one, I need to add the key of CorpAID pointing to the list of a SiteID owned by more than one AID.

Here's should be the result:

```
 Array([0]=> Array(
        [SiteID] => 1
        [Balance] => 2000
        [MinBalance] => 1000
        [MaxBalance] => 500
        [OwnerAID] => 1
        [GroupID] => 1
        [Deposit] => 10000
        [Reload] => 0
        [Redemption] => 0
        [CorpAID] => Array(
                      [0] => 1
                      [1] => 4 
    )
```

Is it possible to make it? Please guide me in proper way, I appreciate your concern and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can someone help me please, I know it's a quite easy for all of you guys. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make it. Question answered. Next please.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have your IDs set as children. It would be better to use these unique IDs in the **keys** for **easier identification**.

From

```
[1] => Array (
  [SiteID] => 1
  ...
)
```

to

```
[1] => Array ( // SiteID
  ...
)
```

And I would change the result of the second function ($this->combined).

From

```
[0] => Array (
  [AID] => 1
  ...
)
```

to

```
[1]=> Array ( // AID ID
  ...
)
```

This would be needed afterwards

```
foreach($this->combined as $aid) {
  $aidID = key($aid);
  foreach($aid as $siteID) {
    $this->arrays[$siteID]['CorpAID'][] = $aidID;
  }
}
```